# SOQL Includes with Field Value?

Tags: apex, soql, dynamic-soql, multi-select

I'd like to add a

```
FROM Account WHERE Clients_for_Job_Opportunities__c INCLUDES (AVTRRT__Job__c.Account.Name)
```

line to my SOQL query but at the moment it looks like I can only add static values.

So really my goal is to use the includes to only look at Accounts where the AVTRRT__Job__c.Account.Name is a value in the Clients_for_Job_Opportunities__c multi-select picklist field.

Can I create a variable to hold this information within the trigger?

Thanks! PS Trigger-in-progress below:

```
trigger JobsEmail on AVTRRT__Job__c (before insert, before update) {
   for (AVTRRT__Job__c myJob : Trigger.new) {
      if (myJob.Send_CCP__c != NULL) { 
         List<Account> toemail = [SELECT Id, Account_Manager_eMail_1__c FROM Account WHERE Clients_for_Job_Opportunities__c INCLUDES (**AVTRRT__Job__c.Account.Name**)];
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To do what you are looking to do you need to split the Multi-select picklist into a list of strings and use the IN function instead of INCLUDES.  Something like this should work for you.

```
list<string> vals = account.Clients_for_Job_Opportunities__c.split(';');
string condition = ''
for(string val : vals) {
    condition += ',\'' + val + '\''
}
//remove the first comma
condition = condition.substring(1, condition.length() - 1);

string query = 'Select Id, Name FROM Account WHERE Clients_for_Job_Opportunities__c IN (' + condition + ')'
list<Account> accounts = Database.query(query);
```

Can't take full credit here as I learned this technique a while back from @sfdcfox.  Used it a few times and works well

https://developer.salesforce.com/forums?id=906F00000008yY9IAI

Answer (score 2):

Tried the solution mentioned above, but that din't work well for me. Modified that to work, thought it be shared, here:

```
Public List<String> vals {get;set;}

   Public string selectedVal{get;set;} //Will be using this in VF page to capture the user selected multiselect list values.

Public static List<sobject> sobjectList {get;set;}


    vals = selectedVal.split(';');

    string condition = '';

    for(string val : vals) {

       condition += ',\'' + val + '\'\'';

    }

    //remove the first comma

    condition = condition.substring(1, condition.length() - 1);

    String str = condition.replaceAll(',',';'); //Returns a string separated by semicolon, eg: ('A;B'), THAT IS A AND B.

    string query = 'Select Id, Name FROM Account WHERE Clients_for_Job_Opportunities__c INCLUDES (' + str + ')';//Includes works here, and str provides the string separated by Semicolon.

    sobjectList=Database.query(query);
```

Comment: Did this code really works? I think it won't even compile.

Answer (score 1):

Previous snippet allowed us to get the selected values of multiselect list as ('A;B'). This one allows us to get the values as ('A', 'B')

```
Public List<String> vals {get;set;}

Public string selectedVal{get;set;} //Will be using this in VF page to capture the user selected multiselect list values.

Public static List<sobject> sobjectList {get;set;}


vals = selectedVal.split(';');

string condition = '';

for(string val : vals) {

   condition += '\''+val+'\''+',';

}
condition = condition.substring(0, condition.length() - 1); //Returns a string separated by semicolon, eg: ('A' , 'B'), THAT IS A OR B.

string query = 'Select Id, Name FROM Account WHERE Clients_for_Job_Opportunities__c INCLUDES (' + condition + ')';//Includes works here, and str provides the string separated by Semicolon.
Sobjectlist=Database.query(query);
```

Answer (score 0):

This may seem obvious but I hope it'll help some folk:
Here it is checking for just one item in the multipicklist array.

```
string anItem = 'item4';
string query = 'SELECT Id, name FROM Account WHERE  (MultiPicklistItems__c INCLUDES (\'' + anItem +'\'))';
//SELECT Id, name FROM Account WHERE  (MultiPicklistItems__c INCLUDES ('item4'))
```